# Here Map Integration within the childfragment is it possible

Tags: android, here-api

Is it possible to integrate the here.com or nokia map within the fragment portion or fragment contains childfragment within this can nokia map embedded?. If possible share me the examples.

Comment: I would like to propose also an alternative, when this is suitable for your usecase. Maybe you should consider using MapView instead of MapFragment to embed HERE Maps in your fragment. So you can get rid of the childfragments with the same funcitonality.

Comment: <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />  how you will embed with in this above map view class?

Comment: First of all, if you want HERE Maps, use the HERE Maps MapView, not the Google one :-) In your fragment xml, it could be like this: 
    <com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /> and then call  MapEngine.getInstance().init(getActivity(), yourEngineInitListener) and handle the results.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, nested fragments are supported by Android. You can probably define your own fragment and nest a com.here.android.mapping.MapFragment and it should work.

Comment: I tried it not worked for me, but android document say that Fragment layout can't inflate the fragment class? If you have resolve this problem please share me the snippet. it will be helpful to me and others.